# How to pass model's obejct to existing view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating application in MVC3. I have a ConferenceController which has a Create() View like this:

namespace Configurator.Controllers
{
    public class ConferenceController : BaseController

```
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {           
        return View(new ConferenceModel());
    }
}
```

}

I have a drop down on this Create View which contains list of Products. On selection of a particular product i am getting the detail of that product in ConferenceModel's object this way:

1. To get the product ID i am using jquery:

$("#ddlProductList").change(function () {
            $.get('/Conference/GetProductDetailByProductID/', { ProductID: $(this).val() }, function (response) {
            });
        });

1. Created a function in ConferenceController which will gets called when drop down change events fire.

   public ActionResult GetProductDetailByProductID(string ProductID)
       {
           return View(ConferenceModel.GetProductDetailByProductID(ProductID));
       }
2. Created a function in ConferenceModel and fetch the product detail on the basis of ProductID from database:

   ```
   public static ConferenceModel GetProductDetailByProductID(string ProductID)
   {
       ConferenceModel obj = new ConferenceModel();

       // Logic goes here to to get the details of product on the basis of productID and returning the object.

       return obj;
   }
   ```
3. When i tried to check this functionality its giving me error that it didn't find any view to display data at this section COnferenceController page:

   ```
   public ActionResult GetProductDetailByProductID(string ProductID)
   {
       return View(ConferenceModel.GetProductDetailByProductID(ProductID));
   }
   ```
4. My question is can i use the existing Create() view to display the data or i have to create a another view with this name: GetProductDetailByProductID()

Anyone has idea about this issue then please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may specify view name using

```
return View("viewname", model)
```

By default the name of the action is used as view name.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overload for the View method which allows you to specifiy a view name:

> return View("Create", ConferenceModel.GetProductDetailByProductID(ProductID));

Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460310.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You're looking to get the product details using jQuery from the client script.

Instead of replying with:

```
public ActionResult GetProductDetailByProductID(string ProductID)
{
    return View(ConferenceModel.GetProductDetailByProductID(ProductID));
}
```

Why not simply return a string of JSON?

```
public JsonResult GetProductDetailByProductID(string ProductID)
{
    return this.Json(ConferenceModel.GetProductDetailByProductID(ProductID));
}
```